# Video overlay not showing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put an overlay on a video, but it does not show.

The dotted line only shows on left and right and the white overlay does not show at all. I've also tried with `z-index` but no result. I'm using Bootstrap.

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
#player {
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#video-div {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.outer-container {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.inner-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.video-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="row" id="video-row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="video-div" align="center">
      <div class="outer-container">
        <div class="inner-container">
          <div class="video-overlay">Some text here</div>
          <video id="player" src="pathToFile" autoplay muted></video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding a z-index: 100; in the .video-overlay it may be that it gets pushed down for some reason. i presume its the .video-overlay u want to show in front of the video.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Can you, please, add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Your welcome and done. i put it in an answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a z-index: 100; in the .video-overlay it may be that it gets pushed down for some reason. i presume its the .video-overlay u want to show in front of the video

```
.video-overlay {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}
```